# Powershell: Convert an array to sequence of arguments to pass them to an exe application through Octopus dashboard

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I work with Octopush dashboard:

[image]

Code on screenshot brings me a list of TFS change sets.
So I already have the list of my IDs.
I need to run some exe file and pass parameters to this exe
in following way through C#:

```
 string cParams = "\"Test proj name\" " + "3.22.652.965863 " + "QA " + "false " + "463841" + " 464268" + " 463450" + " 463841" + " 463167" + " 458908" + " 462917" + " 462780" + " 462429" + " 461225" + " 460414";
        var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\ptnas1\home_dirs\michaelb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Changesetes\Changesetes\bin\Debug\Changesetes.exe", cParams);
```

Or in PowerShell it works this way:

```
start "" "\\ptnas1\home_dirs\michaelb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Changesetes\Changesetes\bin\Debug\Changesetes.exe" "Test proj name"  3.22.652.965863 QA false 463841 464268 463450 463841 463167 458908 462917
pause
```

I need to combine betwwen my hard-coded argements "proj name", "version num", "string1", "false" and the list of IDs I received.
How can I make it work in Powershell?

Comment: What are you having an issue with? Powershell execution policy's? Calling  .exe's? Passing parameters? Or the specific application?   You say `it works this way` and then ask `how to make it work`, so I'm confused as to what the question is.

Comment: Have a look at [Invoke-Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849893.aspx) in powershell, you could build your code and then run it with the invoke-expression command.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't crear.
I've edited my question.
I need to combine between dynamic array and few constants and pass it as arguemnts to my exe.
List of Ids should always be at the end of arguments list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Exe = '\\ptnas1\home_dirs\michaelb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Changesetes\Changesetes\bin\Debug\Changesetes.exe'
$Params = "Test proj name " + "3.22.652.965863 " + "QA " + "false " + "463841" + " 464268" + " 463450" + " 463841" + " 463167" + " 458908" + " 462917" + " 462780" + " 462429" + " 461225" + " 460414"
&$Exe $Params
```

Depend on your native command, you might need to join the params as array first

```
$Params = "Test proj name","3.22.652.965863","QA ","false" [etc.]
&$Exe $Params
```

Using your Example, you can still keep using System.Diagnostics.Process:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($Exe,$Params)
```

Another Option is using WMI:

```
([WMICLASS]"ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").Create("$Exe $Params")
```

And of course PowerShell `Start-Process` with the `-ArgumentList` Parameter

**EDIT**

Separate your Constants and Dynamic Variables,

```
$Exe = `\\ptnas1\home_dirs\michaelb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Changesetes\Changesetes\bin\Debug\Changesetes.exe`
$Constants = "Test proj name","3.22.652.965863","QA" etc.
$Dynamic = "462917","462780","462429","461225","460414"

&$Exe $Constants $Dynamic
```

Or use one of the other Execution options

Comment: The last answer looks like it should work.
Thank you.
I'm going to try it.

Comment: It doesn't work.
I have the same exception for $Exe, $Constants and $Dynamic:
is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: what is the exeption?

Comment: Exceptions:
$Exe it is not recognized as an internal or external command.
$Constants it is not recognized as an internal or external command.
$Dynamic it is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: do `test-path $exe` is it true?

Comment: C:\Users\michaelb\Desktop>$Exe = '\\ptnas1\home_dirs\michaelb\Documents\Visual S
tudio 2015\Projects\Changesetes\Changesetes\bin\Debug\Changesetes.exe'
'$Exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\michaelb\Desktop>$Constants = "Test proj name","3.22.652.965863","QA"
'$Constants' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\michaelb\Desktop>$Dynamic = "462917","462780","462429","461225","460414
"

Answer (score 0):

```
    $argumentList = "`"Test proj name`" 3.22.652.965863 QA false 463841 464268 463450 463841 463167 458908 462917"
    start-process -FilePath "\\ptnas1\home_dirs\michaelb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Changesetes\Changesetes\bin\Debug\Changesetes.exe" -ArgumentList $argumentList
```

Comment: How can I concatenate my dinamic array of ids $changesets wtih variables $projName, $version, $envName and $resolve?
Something like:
$params=$projName+ $version+ $envName + $resolve + $changesets?

Answer (score 0):

My answer based on code that suggested by [Avshalom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4568320/avshalom) that has been modified:

```
$Exe = `\\ptnas1\home_dirs\michaelb\Documents\Visual Studio 

2015\Projects\Changesetes\Changesetes\bin\Debug\Changesetes.exe`
$Constants = "Test proj name","3.22.652.965863","Dev","false"
$Dynamic = "462917","462780","462429","461225","460414"

$all = $Constants + $Dynamic | select -uniq

&$Exe $all
```

The problem is that it is impossible to pass two parameters to .NET concole application in this way:

```
$Exe = `\\ptnas1\home_dirs\michaelb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Changesetes\Changesetes\bin\Debug\Changesetes.exe`
$Constants = "Test proj name","3.22.652.965863","QA" etc.
$Dynamic = "462917","462780","462429","461225","460414"

&$Exe $Constants $Dynamic
```

Because application never receives that last argument. I suppose powershell just ignore the second one.